# How to draw right angle connectors and endpoints with draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I would like to draw electrical circuits with right angles in connectors, but I am not able to see this option in draw.io, they are always rounded.

Most circuits have right angles ...
A simple example http://wpcontent.answcdn.com/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Resistors_in_series_and_parallel.svg/195px-Resistors_in_series_and_parallel.svg.png

As endpoint (see example above), I am using right now a BPMN start icon

Answer (score 3):

Select any/all edges that have the wrong rounding. On the right panel, under the style tab, there's a pull-down to select the edging stlye:

[image: Edge corner styling pull-down in format panel]

Select "Sharp" in that pull-down. Further down that panel is a "Set as default style" button that will set the current style for all new edges.

[image: Set as default style button in format panel]

Comment: "Sharp" (vs. "Rounded" or "Curved") is not enough to get right angles. With "Sharp" you **could** have 45 deg angles (or 21 deg or whatever).  To have the connector line turn only at 90 degree angles, you also need to select the "Orthogonal" style for "Waypoints".  If you prefer the text based style definition (Edit Style), it'd be "edgeStyle=orthogonalEdgeStyle".  See also @030's answer from Jan 22, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

Select the following icon:

[image]

and then when a line is drawn it is possible to create angles.